# Internet or public network access from Snowflake warehouse : For UDF

Tags: python, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, user-defined-functions

I have created a Python UDF in Snowflake SQL (followed this [link](https://medium.com/snowflake/running-pip-packages-in-snowflake-d43581a67439))  that calls the python code of an application that my company has written. The python code requires public internet access to communicate with a server hosted by my company to execute some data extraction/load job.

Currently when I call the UDF it fails with the below error:

```
<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0xffff6c94c9d0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution')) in function ETL_EXTENSION with handler etl_core
```

Can someone tell me how we can enable Internet or public network access from Snowflake warehouse.
In [this](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/udf/python/udf-python-designing#label-udf-python-security) link it is stated that "Network access" from UDF is prohibited.

Is that the case here or is there any way to enable this ? Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: External Functions can call into cloud hosts code. ( https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/external-functions  )And python code can call UDF ( https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/snowpark/python/calling-functions ) so there is a small chance you could weave those two things together.

Answer (score 0):

Currently the Snowflake Python UDFs are running into a sandbox-ed environment and have certain restrictions, amongst which public network access.

Answer (score 0):

[External network access overview](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/external-network-access/external-network-access-overview):

> You can create secure access to specific network locations external to Snowflake, then use that access from within the handler code **for user-defined functions (UDFs)** and stored procedures. You can enable this access through an external access integration.
>
> With an external access integration, you can:
>
> - Write UDF and procedure handlers that access external locations.
> - Allow or block access to locations on a network external to Snowflake.
> - Use secrets that represent stored credentials, rather than using literal values, within handler code to authenticate with external network locations.
> - Specify which secrets are allowed for use with external network locations.