# How to call Rest API directly in Snowflake?

Tags: rest, stored-procedures, get, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to call rest API directly in snowflake. For that I am trying to use Python Stored Procedure. As usual I was trying to invoke requests.get() method. But unfortunately Snowflake don't support building http connection at the present. According to [I need to execute external application from Snowflake. Any option executing shell script using snowflake query window.](https://community.snowflake.com/s/question/0D73r0000065c7bCAA/detail). I need to use external function. But I donot have access to aws account and will not be provided due to various reason.

Can any one please suggest any alternative method.

For instance we are using [public REST API](https://api.publicapis.org/entries)

If not possible , still can you please suggest some great nearest solution without using any External function.

The snowpark code is:

```
import snowflake.snowpark as snowpark
from snowflake.snowpark.functions import col, avg, as_integer
import requests
def main(session: snowpark.Session): 
    r = request.get('https://api.publicapis.org/entries')
    return r
```

### Error in  Snowpark

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "urllib3/connection.py", line 174, in _new_conn
    conn = connection.create_connection(
  File "urllib3/util/connection.py", line 72, in create_connection
    for res in socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, socket.SOCK_STREAM):
  File "/usr/lib/python_udf/7514b8b71a5770c388d7c6f6030134a2a250933021f5c5a0e176ded90a60847a/lib/python3.8/socket.py", line 918, in getaddrinfo
    for res in _socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags):
socket.gaierror: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 714, in urlopen
    httplib_response = self._make_request(
  File "urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 403, in _make_request
    self._validate_conn(conn)
  File "urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 1053, in _validate_conn
    conn.connect()
  File "urllib3/connection.py", line 363, in connect
    self.sock = conn = self._new_conn()
  File "urllib3/connection.py", line 186, in _new_conn
    raise NewConnectionError(
urllib3.exceptions.NewConnectionError: <urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0xffff728c2c10>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "requests/adapters.py", line 486, in send
    resp = conn.urlopen(
  File "urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 798, in urlopen
    retries = retries.increment(
  File "urllib3/util/retry.py", line 592, in increment
    raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))
urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='api.publicapis.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /entries (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0xffff728c2c10>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution'))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  Worksheet, line 5, in main
  File "requests/api.py", line 73, in get
    return request("get", url, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "requests/api.py", line 59, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "requests/sessions.py", line 589, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "requests/sessions.py", line 703, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "requests/adapters.py", line 519, in send
    raise ConnectionError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='api.publicapis.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /entries (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0xffff728c2c10>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution'))
```

Comment: [Internet or public network access from Snowflake warehouse : For UDF](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77028620/5070879)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this [walkthrough](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CXnjvyeb-Q8&ab_channel=SnowflakeDevelopers) from snowflake explains that process

note that this won't work on trial accounts since one cannot create  external access integrations objects, but currently the process is to

- [create network policy](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/create-network-policy)
- [create external access integration](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/create-external-access-integration)
- create (python) udf that does requests

update: here is the code to copy paste and
[here](https://medium.com/snowflake/connect-the-dots-external-apis-with-snowflakes-external-network-access-88471e8d912c) is the code i copy pasted from

```
-- make network rule 
CREATE OR REPLACE NETWORK RULE ifconfignr
 MODE = EGRESS
 TYPE = HOST_PORT  --   indicates that the network rule will allow outgoing network traffic based on the domain of the request destination.
 VALUE_LIST = ('www.ifconfig.me');

 -- make access integration , doesnt work on trial ccounts:
CREATE OR REPLACE EXTERNAL ACCESS INTEGRATION ifconfigeai
 ALLOWED_NETWORK_RULES = (ifconfignr)
 ENABLED = true;

-- make udf 
create or replace function myfun()
returns varchar
language python
runtime_version = '3.8'
EXTERNAL_ACCESS_INTEGRATIONS = (ifconfigeai)
handler = 'myfun'
packages=('requests')
as
$$
import requests 
def myfun():
  r=requests.get('https://www.ifconfig.me')
  return r.text
$$;
 
-- check if it works 
select  myfun()
```

Answer (score 0):

[External Network Access](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/external-network-access/external-network-access-overview) currently in Public Preview in AWS will enable you make external calls to a REST API.

Comment: Thank you for your quick Response. 
I completely agree with your solution. But unfortunately, we don't have AWS Credentials. 
I think for now as an alternative solution, we need to call REST API in Informatica cloud by using python script or Shell Command. :(

Comment: It is in Private Preview in Azure, not sure on GCP. It should go into General Availability for both AWS and Azure this fall.